# Check null response in omdnapi

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to fetch information of movies using omdbapi... I am able to get the information, when it is a valid movie title, i want to display a message when the title doesnt exists. What is wrong with the code?

```
$scope.searchMovie= function(){
      $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t='+$scope.name+'&y='+$scope.year+'').success(function (response) {
        var len=response.length;
        if(len === null)
        {
            alert("No records found!");
        }
        else{
        $scope.movieSearch=response;
        }

      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Api response has Response field. You can use this field to determine if movie was found (`respone.Response=="True"`) or not (`respone.Response=="False"`).

Try this:

```
$scope.searchMovie= function(){
      $http.get('http://www.omdbapi.com/?t='+$scope.name+'&y='+$scope.year+'').success(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.Response == "False")
        {
            alert("No records found!");
        }
        else if (response.Response == "True")

        }

      });
  };
```